# problem on adjective agreement in french

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, moyen-français

> Il y avait la souris courant dans les rayons d'un supermarché, nichée dans l'emballage d'une baguette et maintenant… flottant dans la canette de Coca-Cola.

Why the adjective "flottant" is a masculine singular instead of using  "flottante"
which is a feminine singular ? （canette is a feminine singular）

Answer (score 4):

De la même façon qu'on écrit « courant », plus haut dans la phrase, et non <strike>« courante »</strike>, ce n'est pas un adjectif mais le participe présent de *flotter*.

Le participe présent des verbes est invariable.

Answer (score 1):

COMPLÉMENT DE RÉPONSE

L'adjectif lui-même ne s'emploie avec un nom que si la chose mentionnée est flottante en vertu d'une fonctionnalité qui lui est reconnue explicitement ou implicitement en plus de celles sur lesquelles est fondée la base de son existence.

> - Glaces flottantes, mines flottantes, bases flottantes, Île flottante (amas de végétation dans l'eau),  Île flottante entremets très léger, flottant sur une crème à la vanille), ligne flottante (ligne soutenue à fleur d'eau, pêche), pont flottant, …

Il existe dans ce contexte une frontière assez difficile à reconnaitre ; on dira « des arbres flottants » en analogie avec « des glaces flottantes » parce que les contextes de la glace détachée des banquises et donc, qui flotte, et des arbres arrachés des banques des rivières et donc que l'on voit souvent en train de flotter, existent en tant que réalités normales, habituelle mais accessoire à une réalité de base qui prédomine largement (la glace fait partie des banquises la plus grande partie du temps, par exemple). Si une souris est tombée dans un récipient d'eau on ne dira pas « une souris flottante dans un récipient d'eau » parce qu'il n'y a aucune habitude dans cette action. Cependant, il existe indubitablement cette notion de réalité normale, habituelle, pour les hippopotames, mais malgré cela on ne dira quand même pas « des hippopotames flottants » ; dans ce dernier cas on peut penser que cela est seulement en raison qu'une réalité prédominante n'existe pas vraiment et que tous les hippopotames ont cette habitude.

Si par exemple quelqu'un nous parle de voitures flottantes, bien que nous n'ayons jamais entendu parler de ces véhicules, on comprends tout de suite qu'il s'agit de voitures normales qui en plus de leur fonction habituelle on celle de pouvoir flotter sans être endommagées. Si dans un contexte de fortes pluies et d'inondations on nous dit qu'il y avait des voitures flottantes qui se déplaçaient dans les eaux en crue, on ne saura pas très bien de quoi il s'agit, ou alors, si l'on est déjà dans l'ère des voitures flottantes, on ne pensera pas qu'il s'agit de voitures normales pas encore pleine d'eau et qui vont à la dérive un moment avant de couler.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!